# Getting access to repo forbidden from SVN

Tags: svn, command-line, permissions

I'm running a batch script to manage SVN commits as part of a Jenkins build.

```
svn checkout http://dssubvsn.it.global.mycompany:95/repos/Credit/Risk/trunk/client.risk.ui/src/ThirdPartyBinaries/MyCompany.Product.RiskService--username svn-our-build --password HIDDENFROMSTACKOVERFLOW!

copy d:\flow\Tools\Hudson\data\jobs\MyCompany.RiskService-Deploy\workspace\src\MyCompany.RiskService\bin\Release\MyCompany.RiskService.dll d:\temp\RiskService\ReportsDir\MyCompany.RiskService /Y
copy d:\flow\Tools\Hudson\data\jobs\MyCompany.RiskService-Deploy\workspace\lib\MyCompany..Services.Gui.Json.dll d:\temp\RiskService\ReportsDir\MyCompany.RiskService /Y
copy d:\flow\Tools\Hudson\data\jobs\MyCompany.RiskService-Deploy\workspace\lib\MyCompany..Services.Gui.ApacheMessageQueue.dll d:\temp\RiskService\ReportsDir\MyCompany.RiskService /Y
copy d:\flow\Tools\HudsoIn\data\jobs\MyCompany.RiskService-Deploy\workspace\src\MyCompany.RiskService\bin\Release\MyCompany.RiskService.XmlSerializers.dll d:\temp\RiskService\ReportsDir\MyCompany.RiskService /Y

svn commit d:\temp\RiskService\ReportsDir\MyCompany.RiskService --username svn-build --password FIXME! --message "Auto: Update MyCompany.RiskService dependencies in Reports"
```

The error message I receive is:

**svn: Commit failed (details follow):**

**svn: access to '/repos/Credit/!svn/act/30c483b5-ea4e-8543-b4f4-a9349eca5319' forbidden**

I've anonymised the script but left the capitalisation in place just in case this is an issue.

I've been informed by IT that the scn-build account has read and write on the SVN Repo.  If I use my SVN account when commiting the files in the script, above, everything is commited correctly.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I can't see real error message in code?! Am I blind? Did you try to repeat commit by hand **exactly as in this example**?

Comment: No, you're not blind, I'm just thick.  Error message now added

Comment: Because I was downvoted by anonymous here, you have to repeat my way and find (possible) answer by own hands and mind. I was demotivated, sorry. Use shortened error-message for search, even on this site is enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your current dir before `svn co` is **not** `d:\temp\RiskService\ReportsDir\`, **you will not get** after checkout your Working Copy with from this URL in `d:\temp\RiskService\ReportsDir\MyCompany.RiskService`.

cd or define target for checkout is more safe way

Comment: I've given this to Lazy Badger as once I put the error message on his comment led directly to the answer.  The issue here was the casing of the URL

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that the d:\temp\RiskService\ReportsDir\MyCompany.RiskService directory is not under SVN version control -- that is, it is a regular directory where you just copied files to.  SVN does not know where in the SVN repository to place these files upon commit.

You should check out an existing directory first (where you want to add the .dll's -- say c:\temp for the sake of example), copy the .dlls over, add them to the local repository (of c:\temp), then commit the changes (adds).

Also, I noted that some of the dlls are copied from the libs, others from thew src folder.  This seems suspicious (a possibility of error, not necessarily related to the SVN problem you asked about)

Comment: ReportsDir *can not to be* under version control. `ReportsDir\MyCompany.RiskService` **must to be** Working Copy

Comment: I'm not sure why you say ReportsDir cannot be under version control.  I agree it does not have to be and it is sufficient if MyCompany.RiskService is under version control.

Comment: Because it *can be unversioned* (not *cannot be under version control*!!!) . I see at my TEMP folder with WC-folders inside